# Zend Framework Route analog

Tags: zend-framework, routes

This is a rails 3 code

match '/articles(/:year(/:month(/:day)))' => 'posts#index'"

that match url where some parts can be omitted to post controller and index action

What is the most elegant way to make the same in Zend Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this route should be enough:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'articles/:year/:month/:day',
    array(
        'year'       => date("Y"),
        'month'      => date("m"),
        'day'        => date("d"),
        'controller' => 'post',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ),
    array(
        'year' => '\d+',
        'month' => '\d+',
        'day' => '\d+',
    )
);
```

Defaults to current day/month/year